# Can't get No Match Found for table data not matching search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which I am filtering to get the data that matches that data in the table. For now, I am getting the data that I am inputting into the search bar. I am using HTML and Javascript.

Problem: I also want a 'no match found' to appear and while this is working, it is only working for the top row. For example. I am only getting 'no match found' if the any of the letter does not appear in the top row. But i want no match found to appear for all the rows that does not match the search criteria.

Html(EDIT)

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." style="margin-left:-240px">
<div class="noResults" style="display:none; margin-left:-240px">No Match Found</div>

<table class="newtable" style="table-layout:fixed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div style="width:350px">Document name</div></th>
        <th><div style="margin-left:10px; width:100px">Client</div></th>
        <th><div style="margin-left:10px; width:100px">Date uploaded</div></th>
        <th><div style="margin-left:10px">File</div></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
{% for file in docs %}
<tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width:350px"><a href="/media/{{ file.Filename }}">{{ file.Document_name }}</a></div></td>
        <td><div style="margin-left:10px; width:100px">{{ file.Client }}</div></td>
        <td><div style="margin-left:10px; width:100px">{{ file.Date }}</div></td>
        <td><div style="margin-left:10px">{{ file.Filename }}</div></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function  ()  {
    (function  ($)  {
      $("#myInput").keyup(function  ()  {
        var  rex  =  new  RegExp($(this).val(),  "i");
        $("#myTable tr").hide();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function  ()  {
          return  rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
        $(".noResults").hide();
        if ($("#myTable tr:visible").length == 0)  {
          $(".noResults").show();
        }
      })
    }(jQuery));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have test it and found it is working. May be the question is not clear. jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4u5yf3kw/1/

Comment: @MashukurRahman The documents list is being taken from another source, so we have a list of documents on the page. So I'm not sure its because of that.

Comment: @MashukurRahman i have updated the HTML section, does it make a difference?
Right now the js is working only for the first row in the table. E.g. if i search for the first row, the "no match found" does not appear (expected). But if i search for anything else that exists in the table, "no match found" appears (not expected).

Comment: @LIoyd move the for loop inside the tbody. I think that will fix the problem.

Comment: @MashukurRahman that worked!!! Thanks